# How to get next_posts_link working with a customised page

Tags: posts

I have a customised page using a template and am trying to make use of next_posts_link and previous_posts_link to have buttons at the bottom of the news page.  Trouble is when clicking on them it successfully shows "/home/news/page/2/" as the page but ignores it and still shows the original 10 posts.

I have a filter on the page which I suspected could be the culprit, but have tried removing it with no joy.

Very much appreciate help from the Wordpress brains on here!

```
<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

$cat = ( isset( $_GET['category_select'] ) ) ? $_GET['category_select'] : 1;
$args = array (
    'cat'            => $cat,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And then

```
_e( '<span class="olderLink">');
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $query->max_num_pages );
_e( '</span>');
_e('&nbsp');
_e( '<span class="newerLink">');
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
_e( '</span>');
```

Full code at : http://pastebin.com/4vVEHiKc

Comment: Please add your code to your question

Comment: Thanks Pieter, but I did; it's in the pastebin comment at the bottom.

Comment: No, what I meant is, paste your code in your question, not a pastebin. Pastes get removed, and if this happens, there is no future reference for others that finds your questions. Secondly, many users skip questions where they need to open multiple browser windows to read one question, it is frustrating and inconvenient. :-)

Comment: Ok, sorry didn't realise.  I used pastebin when I asked my first question yesterday as my code was more than the maximum number of characters.

Comment: Pro tip, if you add code, indent each line with 4 spaces or highlight your code and click on the `{}` sign above the editor. This will add your code in a code block. I suspect this is a static front page, then this line `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;` must be `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;`

Comment: Thanks Pieter.  That made a difference in as much as it's kept the "Older Entries" button displaying, but it still doesn't work.  Any other thoughts?  (really appreciate your help BTW)

Comment: I cannot see anything obvious that fails your code. Flush your permalinks again. Did you make sure that you get values from `$_GET['category_select']` on pages 2 and up are they what you expect them to be. Simply just `echo $_GET['category_select']` and check the value on each page. Secondly, after this line, `$query = new WP_Query( $args );`, add `echo 'There are ' . $query->max_num_pages . ' pages and ' . $query->found_posts . ' posts';` and see what it returns

Comment: Thanks again.  The 2nd one returns "There are 2 pages and 20 posts" and the 1st one does nothing.  Thoughts?

Comment: That was my initial thought, your GET variable is not getting passed to page 2 etc. You will need to look into refererss here. Also, your GET variable is due to fail as you have wriiten it

Comment: The GET part was given to me yesterday from a different question on here.  I'm still new to WordPress and have got the hang of the basics, but some of it still eludes me.  Any thoughts on where else I can look to find a solution?

Comment: You should rethink the solution to your previous question. I cannot code a solution, but you will have to use some kind of reliable referrer system to store and carry your GET variable between pages, most probably adding a GET variable directly into the page URL

Comment: Thanks Pieter.  I went back and tried again based on your suggestion and it turned out by using $wp_query instead of $query in my loop it now works.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the loop to use $wp_query instead of $query it worked.  My challenge for another day is to delve into the differences between $wp_query and $query!

Comment: Just be careful with this approach, `$wp_query` holds the main query object, and it isn't really recommended to break it as plugins and other theme code relies on what is stored in this main query object :-)

Comment: Thanks Pieter.  Sounds like there's a whole lot of stuff to learn.